# Aptana Studio 3 - Running on Server (Doesn't Work for Some Projects)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana3, radrails

I am able to "Run/Debug on Server" a new Rails project, created in Aptana.

However, "Run/Debug on Server" fails silently for an existing project.

I haven't been able to figure out why the behavior differs.

Here's what shows in the log.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-07-09 16:33:49.264
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.radrails.rails.internal.ui.commands.RunServerHandler.findOrCreateServer(RunServerHandler.java:77)
    at org.radrails.rails.internal.ui.commands.RunServerHandler.execute(RunServerHandler.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: I personally just use rails server on the command line in aptana. Not an answer, but possibly a work-around for the time being

Comment: I should have mentioned that I _can_ run from the command line, but I don't know how to enable step debugging in Aptana/Eclipse that way. That's the real question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I don't know what happened but here is what I did to solve this:

1. Go to `Preferences->Aptana Studio->Web Servers`.
2. Click `New`.
3. Pick `Rails server` from a list.

In the dialog box: *Enter name for the server* (I'm not sure but it's probably better to put the exact name of the project you are setting server for - this is the same name that appears on the list below); Pick a project name from a list you want to configure the server for; Leave **0.0.0.0** and **3000** untouched.

Click OK & enjoy!

Comment: It seems rails server disappears while closing Eclipse. There is NullPointerException while saving the workbench (probably saving rails server state/data or whatever)

Comment: I have the same issue. when i tried your solution, the rails man page is displayed. is my rails configuration is wrong ?